# Function not getting called from the main function

Tags: c, function, call

I am seriously worried that I don't understand the very fundamentals of C programming. I am reading numbers from a text file, and I am going to check if they are prime numbers or not. However, the problem is that the `IsPrime` function is never being called from the `main` function. I have tried making the `number` variable a global and a local variable, but it does not work. Is my basic understand that bad?

Reading from the text file is no problem. It looks like this:

```
73771782    81296771    79982326    75332246    10128193
81643413    76259734    94432076    50063976    91748657
42311916    -1920042    90747362    53851612    43498487
73193311    96685173    39019033    8630045     17
```

Because the `main` function never calls the `IsPrime` function, the consequence is that all numbers are printed out as `is a prime number`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int isPrime(int number);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int number = 0;
    int number2 = 0;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    
    char file_name[] = "C:\\Users\\Erlen\\Desktop\\numbers.txt";
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); 
    
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening the file: \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &number);
    
    while (number != number2) {
        if (isPrime(&number) == 1) {
            printf("Number: %d is a prime number \n", number);
        } else {
            printf("The number %d is a prime number \n", number);
        }
        number2 = number;
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &number);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}

int isPrime(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: 1st) `isPrime(&number)` ==> `isPrime(number)` ... 0th) **turn on and mind your compiler warnings**

Comment: **both of your branches** print 
***is a prime number***. But you pass in the *address*, hence it does not change. Indeed it is very likely that the address is **not** a prime number, being divisible by 4 or 8.

Comment: Jesus, I was a bit tired at the end. I've changed a lot about the code, and I did not realize that the printf has the same statement. Also, I had completely forgotten that & is for addressing. 

17 should be a prime number, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you pass the address of `number` instead of its value to `isPrime`.
- you should iterate `while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) == 1)` to handle all numbers in the file. Your current loop logic is cumbersome and would fail if the first number if `0` or if the file contains identical consecutive numbers.
- it is idiomatic in C to only test if the return value of `isPrime` is non zero.
- the message for composite numbers is incorrect.
- the convention for the exit status is non zero for failure.
- you should take the absolute value of negative numbers.
- you should return `0` for `0` and `1` which are not considered prime numbers.
- you can improve the performance of `isPrime` for large numbers by testing if `i * i <= number` instead of `i < number`, reducing the complexity to **O(sqrt(N))**.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int isPrime(int number);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int number;
    FILE *fp;
    char file_name[] = "C:\\Users\\Erlen\\Desktop\\numbers.txt";

    fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); 
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening the file: \n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) == 1) {
        if (isPrime(number)) {
            printf("Number %d is a prime number\n", number);
        } else {
            printf("Number %d is a not a prime number\n", number);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int isPrime(int number) {
    if (number < 0)
        number = -number;
    if (number < 2)
        return 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: By using while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) == 1 you avoid that the last number in the text file goes in an infinite loop? 

I used  fscanf(fp, "%d", &number); before the while loop, and I had to use number2 =! number to avoid that from happening.

Also, thanks

Comment: @Tungstein: The correct way to test for end of input is using the return value of `fscanf()`, which tells you if a number was converted or if it failed, either because of end of file or because of invalid input that does not convert to a number. As mentioned above, testing if `number != number2` has false positives: if the first number converted is `0`, the whole file is ignored, and if two consecutive numbers are identical, it causes the loop to stop.

Comment: That's a fair point. I used number != number 2 as a desperate quick fix, without thinking about the consequences if the numbers were different in the text file. Merci.

Answer (score 1):

`isPrime(&number)` you pass the address of the variable `number` not its value. Change to `isPrime(number)`

Check the result of the scanf.
`fscanf(fp, "%d", &number);` =>

```
if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) != 1) 
{
    printf("Scanf error\n");
    exit(0);
}
```